# Chrome Extension - Can't make AJAX request to server on other domain

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have a Chrome Content Script and I want to POST data to a remote server using AJAX

```
    $.ajax({
          url: "http://remote_server/endpoint.php",  
          type: "POST",  
          dataType: "json",  
          contentType: "json",  
          data: {"foo": "bar"},
    });
```

I can post it to my locally hosted server if I set the following in manifest.json -

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/"
  ],
```

or

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://localhost/"
  ],
```

However I get an error if try and post the data to a remote server, even when I have either of the following settings in manifest.json -

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/"
  ],
```

or

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://remote_server/"
  ],
```

I thought if you set the permissions [you are allowed to make cross-site requests](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)? So why is this not working?

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   `http://remote_server/endpoint.php`.
>   Origin chrome-extension://koogajpmmcapakdeahannaecjbcfgicl is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Make sure that after making your changes you are reloading the extension:  Settings->Tools->Extensions and clicking the 'Reload' link for your extension.

Comment: It's working now, I was sure I had reloaded the Extension but maybe I overlooked it.